# Getting Wrong Server Name

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

[image]I am executing a query from which i want to get all server name installed on a system
So I did it with this query

```
select srvname  from sysservers
```

It gives me server names but it is not the correct server name it gives me srvname

`WIN-1BKHGVK7J3A\SQLSERVER2008R2`

but this is not my server name also i tried to do it from another way by this query

```
Select @@Servername
```

it also gives above wrong server name `WIN-1BKHGVK7J3A\SQLSERVER2008R2`

But when i did it with this query

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY ('ServerName')
```

it gives correct server name which is `AIS-OCTACORE\SQLserver2008r2`
but limitation with this is it only gives current server name and i want to get all server name installed  on a system
can you please tell why i'm getting wrong servername??
Also how could i get all server names

Comment: Why have you tagged this as Oracle?

Comment: You're getting the wrong name because someone renamed this server after SQL Server was installed (possibly, it's been imaged as a SQL Server installation) and they've not followed the correct advice to get SQL Server's internal information updated after they did the renaming.

Comment: so how could i got correct server name  From a single query

Comment: [How to: Rename a Computer that Hosts a Stand-Alone Instance of SQL Server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143799(v=sql.105).aspx): "use the following steps to update system metadata that is stored in sys.servers and reported by the system function @@SERVERNAME"

Comment: Ok got it but also i want a single query from which i get all server name on my system

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To check what the current values are set to

```
SELECT ServerProperty('machinename') as [machinename]
    ,ServerProperty('ServerName') as [ServerName]
    ,@@ServerName as [@@ServerName];
```

To correct the issue run the following:

```
EXEC sp_dropserver 'old_server_name';
GO

EXEC sp_addserver 'new_server_name', 'local';
GO
```

You will need to restart the SQLSERVER service

Answer (score 3):

This can happen when the server name is changed after SQL Server was installed.

You could try sp_dropserver and sp_addserver to change it back:   http://www.brentozar.com/blitz/servername-not-set/

Im not sure i would though you dont know why it was changed in the first place it might break something.

Answer (score 2):

Although the @@SERVERNAME function and the SERVERNAME property of SERVERPROPERTY function may return strings with similar formats, the information can be different. 
The **SERVERNAME property** automatically reports changes in the network name of the computer.

In contrast, @@SERVERNAME does not report such changes.
 **@@SERVERNAME** reports changes made to the local server name using the sp_addserver or sp_dropserver stored procedure.[technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187944.aspx)

1. To findout "SERVER NAME"

   SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('MACHINENAME')
2. To findout "SERVER NAME" with "INSTANCE NAME" (If its Named Instance)

   SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('SERVERNAME')
3. To findout "CLIENT MACHINE NAME"(Local Machine Name)

   SELECT HOST_NAME()

Comment: How i get all server names In my system i had a Oracle serve , and a Mssqk server From a single query

Comment: SELECT  host_name FROM    v$instance

Comment: v$instance??.. there is nohing like this in MSSQL Server

Comment: i said that for oracle

Comment: How could i do this in MSsql server

Comment: SELECT @@SERVERNAME AS 'Server Name'